# Apache ProxyPass - Error during SSL Handshake with remote server

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, proxypass

Im using proxy pass to redirect http to https backend server (tomcat)

Error im getting is :  Error during SSL Handshake with remote server

My Configuration :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mypersonal.server.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
    ProxyPass /publisher https://localhost:9443/publisher
    ProxyPassReverse /publisher https://localhost:9443/publisher
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm trying to find a way to overcome the verification of SSL, but the following commands appears in grey in my config

```
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
```

Im using Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)

Appreciate your assistance

Comment: The host preserving definition should also be consistent.
[see details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75312619/4444742)

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party here, but somebody might find this useful.
Check your `SSLProxyProtocol` directive. If, for security purposes, you have disabled the protocol that your backend is using, then the handshake will fail.

For example, I was using `SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1 -TLSv1.2` but had to relax it to `SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1` because my backend is still using TLS v1.1.

EDIT in 2023: I just saw this was upvoted recently. If you're still having problems, also check your values for `SSLProxyCipherSuite` (see [apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#SSLProxyCipherSuite) and [values recommended by Mozilla](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS))